# How to check if the array key value is present in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays which are

```
    $key = array(
                "site_url" => "Site URL",
                "current_date" => "Current Date",
                "user_name" => "User name", 
                "name" => "Name of the user",
                "password" => "Password of user",
                "user_email"  => "Email address of new user"
            );
   $tmpl_name = array ("name","url","current_date","email");
```

I want to check the 2nd array values is present in the first array's key value.If not,display which one is different    from first array.

Comment: Did you try any of the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = array(
            "site_url" => "Site URL",
            "current_date" => "Current Date",
            "user_name" => "User name", 
            "name" => "Name of the user",
            "password" => "Password of user",
            "user_email"  => "Email address of new user"
        );
$tmpl_name = array ("name","url","current_date","email");

foreach($tmpl_name as $name) {
    if(array_key_exists($name, $key)) {
       // exists
    } else {
       //does not exist in key
    }
}
```

Comment: This will throw a notice saying that `url` is not valid index

Comment: @PeeHaa : ) It will not throw any more

Comment: Better use `array_key_exists` instead

Comment: @PeeHaa Point to be noted

Answer (score 0):

`array_diff` combined with `array_keys` will do it. Try this:

```
$missing    = array_diff($tmpl_name, array_keys($key));
```

Outputs as:

```
array(2) {
    [1] = string(3) "url"
    [3] = string(5) "email"
}
```

Or you can swap them around:

```
$missing    = array_diff(array_keys($key), $tmpl_name);
```

To get the keys in first array that aren't in the second values.

```
array(4) {
    [0] = string(8) "site_url"
    [2] = string(9) "user_name"
    [4] = string(8) "password"
    [5] = string(10) "user_email"
}
```

Comment: @PeeHaa so swap the parameters?